# How do I use applet methods without extending Applet?

Tags: java, applet

I'm slowly feeling my way around various methods of getting Java to do what I require, but I've come across an issue when attempting to write my own canvas-like class...

Within my class I call `createImage(myMemoryImageSource);` and `repaint();` in an attempt to remove complexity from my main "run" method of my applet.

Despite including `java.awt.*`, `java.awt.image.*` and `java.applet.*`, this class won't compile unless it extends from **Applet**. My class is really just a canvas class so I'd prefer it not to extend Applet.

Am I missing a vital include, or do I have a gross misunderstanding of how I should be implementing my own canvas class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to extend your class from a Canvas.

Comment: Bang on. That was a quick fix. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to subclass, then you'll need an instance with which you can invoke said methods. Also, by convention, if you're going to customize a component, it's best to subclass it.

**Example -**

```
final class Foo extends JFrame{
    Foo(){
        super("Foo Frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

*or*

```
final class Foo{
    private final JFrame frame;
    Foo(){
        frame = new JFrame("Foo Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Your examples will certainly prove useful as I progress with my little project.